# Stream API - How does sorted() operation works if a filter() is placed right after it?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

Take the following code, which is sorting a List and then filtering on it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = List.of(3,2,1);
        
        List<Integer> filtered =  list.stream()
                .sorted() // Does sorted() sort the entire array first ? Then pass the entire sorted output to filter ?
                .filter(x -> x < 3)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println(filtered);
    }
```

Does the entire `sort()` happen first, then gets passed to `filter()` ?

Then isn't that a violation of what streams are supposed to do?

I mean, they are supposed to process **one element at a time**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the entire sort() happen first then gets passed to filter() ?
>
> Then isn't that a violation of what streams are suppose to do ?

No, it isn't. Take a look at the [documentation of the Stream IPA](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps):

> Intermediate operations are further divided into stateless and
> stateful operations. **Stateless operations**, such as **filter** and **map**,
> **retain no state** from **previously seen element** when processing a new
> element -- each element can be processed independently of operations
> on other elements. **Stateful operations**, such as **distinct** and **sorted**,
> may **incorporate state** from **previously seen elements** when **processing
> new elements**.
>
> **Stateful operations** may need to **process** the **entire input before
> producing a result**. For example, one cannot produce any results from
> sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream. As a
> result, under parallel computation, some pipelines containing stateful
> intermediate operations may require multiple passes on the data or may
> need to buffer significant data. Pipelines containing exclusively
> stateless intermediate operations can be processed in a single pass,
> whether sequential or parallel, with minimal data buffering.

That means `sorted` is aware of all previously encountered elements, i.e. it's *stateful*. But `map` and `filter` don't need this information, they are *stateless* and *lazy*, these operations always process elements from the stream source one at a time.

And it's technically impossible to sort the contents of a pipeline by looking at a single element in isolation. `sorted` operates on **all** elements "at once" and hands out a sorted stream to the next operation. You might think of `sorted` as if it becomes a new source of the stream.

Let's take a look at the following stream and analyze how it will be processed:

```
Stream.of("foo", "bar", "Alice", "Bob", "Carol")
    .filter(str -> !str.contains("r")) // lazy processing
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .map(String::toUpperCase)          // lazy processing
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .sorted()                          // <--- all data is being dumped into memory
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .filter(str -> str.length() > 3)   // lazy processing
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .findFirst();                      // <--- the terminal operation
```

Operations `filter` and `map` that precede `sorted` will get applied lazily on each element from the source of the stream and only when it's needed. I.e. *filter* will be applied on the `"foo"`, it successfully passes the *filter* and gets transformed by the *map* operation. Then *filter* gets applied on the `"bar"` and it will not reach the *map*. Then it will be `"Alice"`'s turn to pass the *filter*, and then the *map* will get executed on that string. And so on.

Keep in mind that `sorted()` requires all the data to do its job, so the *first filter* will get executed for all elements from the source and the *map* will be applied on every element that passed the filter.

Then `sorted()` operation will dump all the contents of the stream into memory and will sort the elements that have passed the first filter.

And after the *sorting*, again all elements will be processed *lazily one at a time*. Hence, the *second filter* will be applied **only once** (although `3` element have passed the first filter and were sorted). `"Alice"` will pass the *second filter* and reach the terminal operation `findFirst()` that will return this string.

Take a look at the debugging output from the `peek()` make that the process of execution is happening as described above.

Comment: `sorted` doesn’t have to act like a stand-alone operation. E.g. `sorted().findFirst()` could get converted to the equivalent of `min()` under the hood. Or an optimization like the OP asked for, moving the subsequent `filter` before the `sort` is imaginable. It doesn’t change the fundamental fact that due to `sorted`, as you said, all elements have to be processed even though `findFirst()` is a short-circuiting operation. Whether such optimization(s) happen, is up to the particular implementation. Currently existing are a potential skip of `sort` for `count()` or already sorted sources.